# Comparing names with equals

Tags: scheme, racket

How do I compare names such as this case:

```
(if (= name '(bill)) (write-line '(over)))
```

?

Answer (score 2):

The procedure used for testing equality depends on the type of the operands to be compared. In particular, the `=` procedure is used for comparing between *numbers*:

```
(= 1 1)
```

But that doesn't seem to be the case. If `name` is a symbol:

```
(symbol=? name 'bill)
```

If `name` is a string:

```
(string=? name "bill")
```

If `name` is a single character:

```
(char=? name #\b)
```

If name is *in* a list:

```
(member name '(bill))
```

Finally, if you're not sure of the type of name, you can always use `equal?`:

```
(equal? name "bill")
```

Comment: +1 for the tip at the end. You usually won't go _wrong_ using `equal?`. You might go _slow_ (slower than necessary), is all. For example it would be somewhat faster to compare two symbols with `eq?`, but your program will work correctly if you use `equal?`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it's unlikely that you'd want the name to be `'(bill)`, which is a list consisting of the single symbol `'bill`. You probably just want `'bill` directly. Second, you can't use `=` for a comparison of symbols: `=` is for numeric comparisons. `symbol=?` is probably what you want:

```
(if (symbol=? name 'bill) ...)
```

(Note that there are some other equality functions that will work here too, and you may well see other people use `eq?` or `equal?` in place of `symbol=?` here.)